# Issue when attaching debugger in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a custom Chrome extension and one of the feature is actually to highlight and get the DOM selector from an element when the user is moving the mouse cursor over it.

I've been told it would be quite easy to implement this function using the Chrome Debugger API. I've downloaded a couple of code samples but I alway get the same erroe

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Invocation of form 
debugger.attach(integer, string) doesn't match definition 
debugger.attach(object target, string requiredVersion, optional 
function callback)
at chrome-extension://hgjiapiojommgpfcaijbjlckjajegmoa/js/background.js:16:23
```

Here is my background.js file content

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "toggle");
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request == "captureSelector") {
      console.log(sender);
      console.log("'Capture DOM selector' event detected");

      chrome.debugger.attach(sender.tab.id, "1.0");
    }
  }
);
```

According to the documentation the function is expecting a Debuggee object that could be a tabId so I dont understand why it's failing

Any ideas please?

Comment: `Debuggee` is an object (not an immediate value) with properties listed in the documentation so the valid parameter would be `{tabId: sender.tab.id}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved :)